# Oracle Virtual Box import VMWare Windows 2008 Crash on boot

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

I was given a VMWare image running Windows Server 2008 which was imported on my PC perfectly fine and works.

I really want to run it on my MacBook Pro and would have to use Oracle Virtual Box as it seems there is no VMWare Player for OSX.

According to the Internet, the strategy for opening a VMWare machine in Oracle Virtual Box is to create a new machine and attach an existing hard drive.

On the Mac I tried this and get into a situation "Windows Error Recovery" which I am unable to recover from.

On the PC I get exactly the same problems with Oracle Virtual Box with that same image as I do on the Mac.

On the PC (as stated) I can run the VM in VMWare BUT if I have already attempted to open the  VM in Oracle Virtual Box, the image is corrupted and can't then be opened on the PC with VMWare.

My question is if anyone has any knowledge of what settings need to be changed in Oracle Virtual Box before opening the VM and destroying the image with it.

Many thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by attaching the Windows Server 2008 disk image as additional Storage to another VM that was already working (e.g. an IE8 Win7 VM downloaded from [Microsoft](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)). You can set the hard disk as master or slave, or switch when booting up the main VM.